# how can I set a formula in a box depending a word with conditional formating?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to set a conditional formula with a formula in different boxes depending a word...

So I basically have such a spreadsheet :

| value | factor | task_01 | task_02 | task_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1500 | facteur_01 |  |  |  |
| 4500 | facteur_02 |  |  |  |
| 3000 | facteur_01 |  |  |  |
| 200 | facteur_03 |  |  |  |

depending the word in the column factor, I would like to set a formula like this :

if word in the column B is 'facteur_01'

set the formula `=20%*A/75` in column C

set the formula `=40%*A/75` in column D

set the formula `=40%*A/75` in column E

if word in the column B is 'facteur_02'

set the formula `=10%*A/75` in column C

set the formula `=10%*A/75` in column D

set the formula `=80%*A/75` in column E

I have think about doing it with script, but I guess conditional formatting will be more efficient. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional Formatting is meant to change the format of the cell (its cell background, color, bold or italic, for example); to change values you should use IF statements. For example, in C2:

```
=IF(B2="facteur_01",A2*0.20/75,IF(B2="facteur_02",A2*0.10/75,""))
```

You can use the same process to populate the rest of the values in row 2, and copy and paste down (or drag) ;)

---

Option 2, with different locale. Maybe you need semicolons instead of commas:

```
=IF(B2="facteur_01";A2*0.20/75;IF(B2="facteur_02";A2*0.10/75;""))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but it doesn't look to work when I copy it on my own spreadsheet...

Comment: Could you please show how it differs from your expected output?

Comment: it don't do anything and just tell me "error formula analysis"

Comment: See option 2 if it returns something different!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally change the word "IF" for the french word "SI" and it's know working, and build it with semilicon... it look like that : ```=SI(B2="facteur_01";20%*A2/75;SI(B2="facteur_02";50%*A2/75;;))``` and now works !

Comment: Oh, I'm glad you could work it out!!